# Mathematically scale large elements lesser then small elements

Tags: math

10 elements with the class xxx have different widths and heights. Putting transform: scale(1.1) enlarges the big ones clearly but the small ones barely show difference. This is bad UX. The mathematical question is how to make the bigger elements scale less then the smaller ones:
width 10 should get scale 1.1
width 5 should get scale 1.2

How can i mathematically solve this?

Comment: [Logarithmic scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_scale)

Comment: "Bigger elements get scaled bigger while smaller elements barely scale" and "I would like to have smaller scale more and later scale less": what the hell does this mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question lacks context and details, so it is hard to give a generally meaningful answer. However, the given examples indicate the following solution:

```
x_new = 1 + 1/x_old
```

Where `x_old` is the input value, i.e. 10 or 5.
Using logarithmic scaling instead of just `1/x_old` might be another option, depending on the context.

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate the scenarios i made these pens:

non logarithmic scale: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwRVpj

logarhitmic scale: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VKWLJK

```
var inlineStyle = ''

var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div')
var len = divs.length
while(len--) {
  var elWidth = divs[len].offsetWidth
  var scale = 1+9/elWidth
  inlineStyle += `#${divs[len].id}:hover {
    transform: scale(${scale})
    }`
}
document.getElementById('lolStyle').innerHTML = inlineStyle
```